# Check if list is either empty or only containing zeroes

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list, if-statement

Right now, in my code I have two lists: `aboveAdj1` and `aboveAdj2` which either contain 1s and 0s, or are empty:

```
if len(aboveAdj1) and len(aboveAdj2):
    perAboveFix = 100*int(sum(aboveAdj1) + sum(aboveAdj2))/int(len(aboveAdj1) + len(aboveAdj2))
```

If both `aboveAdj1` and `aboveAdj2` are not empty or all zeros, then I want to calculate the ratio. Is there an efficient/short way of calculating the ratio based on only one of the variables, if the other variable is empty, without having to write a bunch of `if` statements?

For example, if `aboveAdj1` is empty or all zeros, then calculate:

```
perAboveFix = 100*int(sum(aboveAdj2))/int(len(aboveAdj2))
```

and vica-versa.

Comment: would this work? `if len(aboveAdj1) and len(aboveAdj2) and sum(aboveAdj1) and sum(aboveAdj2):` I don't fully understand your question

Comment: What do you mean by "aboveAdj1 is zero"? Do you mean all of the values are zeroes?

Comment: if the only options you're testing for are that `aboveAdj1` is empty or `aboveAdj1` is filled with zeroes, you could do `if sum(aboveAdj1): do_stuff`. The sum of an empty list, or a list filled with zeroes, is `0` which is Falsey.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if it's empty or all zeros

Comment: `any(aboveAdj1)` is a tiny bit faster than `sum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want to check if:

- The lists aren't empty
- and they contain at least one value which is not zero.

The `any()` function just does this for you, since that `any(some_list)` is `True` if the list is not empty and contains at least one non-zero value.

So if you want to calculate the ratio only if **both the lists are valid**, you can do:

```
if any(aboveAdj1) and any(aboveAdj2):
    perAboveFix = 100 * (sum(aboveAdj1) + sum(aboveAdj2)) / (len(aboveAdj1) + len(aboveAdj2))
```

Otherwise, if you want to calculate it when **at least one list is valid**, then you can do:

```
if any(aboveAdj1 + aboveAdj2):
    perAboveFix = 100 * (sum(aboveAdj1) + sum(aboveAdj2)) / (len(aboveAdj1) + len(aboveAdj2))
```

Also note that **you don't need to use the `int()` function** since that, as you said, your lists only contain `0`s and `1`s, and `len()` already returns integer values.

Answer (score 3):

if the only options you're testing for are that aboveAdj1 is empty or aboveAdj1 is filled with zeroes, you could do

```
if sum(aboveAdj1):
    # some non-zero element exists
    do_stuff_as_normal
else:
    do_stuff_differently
```

The sum of an empty list, or a list filled with zeroes, is `0` which is Falsey.

Alternatively if you're just scared about the zero division, you can skip all the conditionals and simply try it, excepting out the case where you might divide by zero. This is a common idiom in Python.

```
try:
    your_normal_division
except ZeroDivisonError:
    alternate_formula
```

Comment: Try-except is the most pythonic in my opinion

Comment: The sum might be zero without all elements being zero.

Comment: `any()` suits the problem better, since it doesn't need to go over the whole list

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is, in general, true, but the OP specifically said that the lists do not contain negative values, so in this case is safe to assume that the sum will be zero only if the list is empty or filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Well the the `sum` of an empty list and a zero list will return 0 meaning that if `aboveAdj1 == ([] or [0,0,0]` then `sum(aboveAdj1) + sum(aboveAdj2) == sum(aboveAdj2)`. This means that the only thing you need to worry about is the `len` of a zero list (ie, `[0,0,0]` should return a `len == 0`). you could handle this with ternary expressions:

```
perAboveFix = 100*int(sum(aboveAdj1) + sum(aboveAdj2))/  #just a break for readability
int((len(aboveAdj1) if sum(aboveAdj1) else 0) + 
(len(aboveAdj2) if sum(aboveAdj2) else 0))
                   ^   ^ checks that sum is not 0
```

Then, all you need to check for is that at least one list has a valid length since dividing by 0 is a math error. by using the built-in `any` function, you can check for both the length and sums at the same time:

```
if any(aboveAdj1) or any(aboveAdj2):
     #expression here
```

since `any` will return false if all the elements are 0 or if its empty.